# Using Indirect function with Max Frequency and If functions

Tags: excel

I currently have a Spreadsheet for recording betting results for a group of friends. Each week we place an accumulator bet and record results of each person's selections: **WIN/LOSS/VOID**. Within the spreadsheet I have created a formula to calculate the Consecutive Number of Wins and Losses per person. The way results have been recorded is a new column is added at the start of the spreadsheet each week. This means that my formula is updating and new weeks are being missed in the range. The formula I am using is the following:

```
={(MAX(FREQUENCY(IF($D2:CE2="w",D1:CE1),IF($D2:CE2="w",0,D1:CE2))))}
```

I have tried to include an INDIRECT Function so that my formula will always look to CELL D2 for the start of the Range expressed in the IF Statement but I cant seem to get it to work.

Any Help would be much Appreciated as I am not great with Excel!!

Many Thanks

Comment: Do you need an array formula for this? If I'm not mistaken, a simple `Countifs()` would work just the same.

Comment: please, post an image of your spreadsheet..

Comment: If I read this question properly I think you need something like `...OFFSET(INDIRECT("D2"),0,0,1,column(<<cell in last columns>>)-3)...`